# What happened to Magus?

Tags: chrono-trigger, chrono-cross

In *Chrono Trigger* the party can go to Time's Eclipse to encounter a version of Magus from a future where Lavos was destroyed and fight the Dream Devourer which is thought to be an earlier form of the Time Devourer because of Schala being in the same spot.

After fighting it, still loosing and being sent away Schala tells the Future Magus that he can never hope to destroy it and to give up sending him away too. Magus laments on this and decided that if he can't save Schala he'll fade away too but if something of him remains then he hopes it can can save Schala and we see a Magus without Memories wandering in a forest.

in *Chrono Cross* after waking Kid up following FATE's destruction Luccia gives Kid a letter from Lucca effectively telling her not to blame herself for whatever happens to her saying that she expects something from the future(s) they negated to seek revenge but also telling Kid that Janus (Magus's real name) will look out for her if not already with her (to which she says hello to him in the letter).

But i didn't see Magus at all in *Chrono Cross*. Since Lucca was for sure that he would be at least looking out for her and something remained of him after he faded away, what happened to Magus?

Comment: I thought that originally, there's a character in Chrono Cross that was supposed to be revealed to be Magus, but they cut that idea.